# Temporarily disable facets in Python's FacetedSearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-py

I have created my own customised `FacetedSearch` class using Pythons Elasticsearch DSL library to perform search with additional filtering in `def search(self)`. Now I would like to reuse my class to do some statistical aggregations. To stay DRY I want to reuse this class and for performance reason I would like to temporarily disable facets calculation when they are not necessary while preserving all the filtering. So question is how can I temporarily omit facets in `FacetedSearch` search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you just want to use the `Search` object's query, but not it's aggregations? In that case just call the object's `search()` method to get the `Search` object and go from there.

If you want the aggregations, but just want to skip the python-level `facets` calculation just use the `build_search` method to get the raw `Search` object including the aggregations.

Comment: Thanks! Furthermore I realised that I need to use standard filter instead of build-in post_filter so I created my own `build_search` function that skips `self.aggregate()` and use different `self.filter(s)`. Is there any reason why `self.build_search()` is automatically run from `__init__`? It's useless in my case.

Comment: The reason why it's run from `__init__` is because it is always needed so it makes sense to run it there instead fo trying to create some form of property that would create it on demand.